# Javascript SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript on Codecademy, and one of the tasks is to use a .push() method to find my name in a string containing many names, with the letters seperated by colons. I don't need it to log to the console just yet, though. It keeps telling me that I have the following Syntax Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Here is my current code:

```
/*jshint multistr:true */
var text = "John Steve Ray John John Steve Connor John Bob Frank Ray Connor John Bob John Bob Jim Connor Bob John Ray Frank";
var myName = "Connor";
var hits = [];
for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
};
if (text[i]==="C") {
    for (var j=i; j<i+myName.length; j++) {
        var hits.push(j);
    };
};
```

All contributions will be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: In line 9, you are declaring `hits` again each time. use `hits.push(j);` instead of `var hits.push(j);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "John Steve Ray John John Steve Connor John Bob Frank Ray Connor John Bob John Bob Jim Connor Bob John Ray Frank";
var myName = "Connor";
var hits = [];
for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
if (text[i]==="C") {
    for (var j=i; j<i+myName.length; j++) {
        hits.push(j);
    };
}
}
```

Remove the var before hits.push().

Make sure you to close the  for loop after if

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "John Steve Ray John John Steve Connor John Bob Frank Ray Connor John Bob John Bob Jim Connor Bob John Ray Frank";
var myName = "Connor";
var hits = [];
for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
if (text[i]==="C") {
    for (var j=i; j<i+myName.length; j++) {
        hits.push(j);
    }
}
};
```

You are declaring `hits` again and you had a forloop `for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {` empty so make sure you are using it right